# How to order same ajax calls in a loop?

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I am getting some information from back end using the following code:

> ```
> angular.forEach(authors, function(author){
>             var authorId = author.id;
>             var url = contextPath + '/book/list/' + authorId;
>             $http({
>                 method: 'GET',
>                 url: url
>             })
>             .then(function(response){
>                 author.books = response.data;
>             })
>         });
> ```

I want to trigger the ajax calls one by one not all at the same time, which means each ajax call would wait for the previous one to be completed. Does anybody know what would be the change in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make call on a sequence basis by using **$timeout**  service in angular as below

```
angular.forEach(authors, function(author){
        var authorId = author.id;
        var url = contextPath + '/book/list/' + authorId;
        $timeout(function(){
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url
        })
        .then(function(response){
            author.books = response.data;
        })
    })},2000);//2000-> milliseconds;
```

This makes your **GET**  request on every 2 seconds. If you know that your call will take some more time set the timeout value as required.

Comment: it still firing all ajax calls at the same time. It just waits two seconds before doing that.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [$q.all()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

> Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of the input promises are resolved.

EDIT:
Ooops , didn't quite read it. $q.all() wait for all promises to resolve, you need to chain them so after one promise is resolved you call another:

```
        somepromise
        .then(function(response){
            return $http({method:"some method",url:"some urlj",data:response});
        }).then(function(response2){
           //chain third and so on
        })
```

basically you need to return promise to be able to chain them

Comment: my ajax calls are the same and they can be a lot in some cases (200 calls). So I can not use your code because it would be a lot to write.